# Change temporiry file path during file uploading

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way to change the default temporary path in uploading file via html form. Or you can understand it as i want to set `$_FILES["uploadfile1"]['tmp_name']` of my choice.

Comment: It's possible, but why does it matter to you where the temporary file is located? You need to move it away from there anyway if you want to keep the file.

Comment: @Pekka i am using a prebuilt function and i need to change it according to it's requirement.

Comment: @yes123 i always accept a true answer. Don't guess anything wrong..:)

Comment: @mansoor no prebuilt function should require changing the temporary file directory. It sounds like there might be a different problem here that should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

At your php.ini change `upload_tmp_dir`

> Perhaps you can set it at your code directly whitout changing it at
>   php.ini using
>
> ```
> ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','/new temp folder');
> ```
>
> but I am not 100% sure it will works..

Comment: Nope, that won't work, because the upload will already have been handled by then. This needs to be in php.ini

Comment: @mansoor not quite: this setting is the only way to do what you need. It just needs to be done in php.ini, not in the PHP file

Comment: @mansoor I have posted 2 ways.
First is the correct one - changing upload_tmp_dir at php.ini, second wont work.

Comment: But why you need to change the temp folder ? Files which are not moved from there will be lost after you close your page. 
Once uploaded you must move your file to some NOT TEMPORARY folder.

Comment: thank's @Svetlio, but i cannot change php.ini, that's the issue.